# Deck blocks on patio stones

Tags: deck, waterproofing, patio

I am planning to build the 16x18ft floating deck in the back of my townhouse. The back patio is paved with 12x24" patio stones and I am trying to figure out if I should remove patio stones and lay the deck blocks on the soil or should I leave patio stones and lay the deck on top of them.

Is there an issue with setting the deck blocks on the patio stones?

I am concerned that if I remove them, I might allow water to collect and stay in that area which might cause foundation problems down the road.

Comment: Water will "collect and stay" far less on the ground than it will on materials like paver stones.

Comment: Hi, what did you end up doing? I have the same question lol

Comment: It worked beautifully. No movement or anything after almost 2 years. The setup was super easy...I laid the deck blocks, laid the beams on them, aligned them by height, and then interconnected the beams (lumber going across in-between beams)

Few neighbors watched what and how I was doing and they decided to do the same

Answer (score 1):

First of all, just laying pavers on dirt is a bad idea unless you live in a bone dry place like Phoenix or Las Vegas.

A deck should be mounted on footings which are concrete blocks which stabilize the deck.

The footings should be below the frost line, otherwise the deck will move up and down every time it freezes and thaws. The frost line in Toronto is about 4 feet deep, so you want the footings to be 5 feet deep to be safe.

Comment: I see where you are coming from but my condominium does not allow us to dig footings. All we can do is a floating deck (deck block + beams + decking). There are few decks like that in my condominium and they turned out to work well. 

Patio stones are sitting on the sand, not just dirt.

Comment: @BogdanYU2DBC If you are building a floating deck, then the larger the surface area of the support pads, the better. So, putting them on top of the pavers is probably the right approach.